# Volley gson exception Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 11

Tags: json, android-volley

i used json befor the only new thing
 is that am using google volley
 on android app
  client side:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.i("asaf","jsone="+response.toString());
                        WorkerSeekerContiner wsc=new WorkerSeekerContiner();
                        Gson gsonConvertFrom = new Gson();

                        wsc=gsonConvertFrom.fromJson(response.toString(), WorkerSeekerContiner.class);
                        Log.i("asaf","list size="+wsc.getList().size());
```

server side:

```
 Gson gsonConvertTo = new Gson();
         String jsonString = gsonConvertTo.toJson(send);
         JSONObject myJsonObj;
         try {
         myJsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
         out.print( myJsonObj.toString());
```

tostring of the JSONObject response: (hold the right data )

> ```
>     {
> "list":[
> [251,"t1","t1","Nov 7, 2018",31.483521,34.596634,9000,"Nov 10, 
>  2013","yardwork","a"]
> ,[252,"t1","t1","Nov 7, 
>  2018",31.483521,34.696634,9000,"Nov 10, 2013","yardwork","a"]
> ]
> }
> ```

but when i try to gsonConvertFrom.fromJson it throws exception:

> wsc=gsonConvertFrom.fromJson(response.toString(),
>   WorkerSeekerContiner.class);

```
       11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804): com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
 Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 11
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:180)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:755)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:721)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:670)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:642)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at asaf.findwork.linkup$1.onResponse(linkup.java:131)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at asaf.findwork.linkup$1.onResponse(linkup.java:1)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5037)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 11
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.expect(JsonReader.java:339)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:322)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:168)
    11-15 16:50:52.792: E/AndroidRuntime(17804):    ... 22 more
```

and last my object just hold a list of objects:

```
public class WorkerSeekerContiner {
    List<WorkerSeeker> list;
```

Workerseeker class:

```
@Entity
public class WorkerSeeker implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Calendar startdate;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Calendar enddate;
    private Double offerprice;
    private Double  latitude;
    private Double longitude;
    private String address;
    private String userName;
    private String type;
    private String description;
```

god dam it :(( 

the problem was useing createNativeQuery wich on use of (List)q3.getResultList(); gave me a list of objects and not a list of WorkerSeeker
errrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

if anyone run in to this problem the fix is really easy just add  
createNativeQuery (sqlqury,**urclass.class**); will return arrayof urclass not objects

Comment: please share your WorkerSeeker class

Comment: ok there it is ( server side, client as same thing without the entity ) ,i sort of got around this problem with stringtokenizer and just build my object from each string still id love to know why this is not working ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createNativeQuery will retrun list of objects on Query.getResultList(); not list of workseeker

 am an idot;/

Comment: Please Explain your answer in detail.